# Air simulation environment

Tags: fluid-dynamics, forces, air, simulations

I will preface this with the fact that I am not a physicist...I am an engineer by trade.  I am working on a research problem that will involve flight of an organism with varying shapes, and I am interested in finding an open-source environment that successfully models the varying forces and whatnot found in the atmosphere.

Basically, I want to create a 3D representation of my flyer and put it into an environment and be able to have natural forces act upon it (to see how it reacts).

Does such a beast exist?

Answer (score 2):

Check out JSBSim (http://jsbsim.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to add models. It is one of the engines in FlightGear (http://www.flightgear.org/).